# Design a CMS site using ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, content-management-system

I'm building a site which mainly has **articles** and I'm using **ASP.NET MVC 5** framework. I want to have an admin page where I can add, edit these article content.

I'm having a problem with designing the structure of this project.
I'm thinking of having a controller class called '`adminController`', where I handle all the requests related to content management.

Is that approach conceptually correct in **ASP.NET MVC**? Because If this was an ASP web forms project, I would simply have two different projects called Public and Admin in a single solution.

I'm quite new to ASP.NET MVC framework and I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do 2 separate projects and can do one.

Since **ASP.NET MVC 4** whe have `Areas` and i suggest you to use it if you want structure your project and separate admin logic from public.

[Here is a tutorial](http://www.itorian.com/2013/10/area-in-mvc-5-with-example-step-by-step.html) that you can check that explain whar `areas` is and how you can work with them.

Comment: I think that's exactly what I was looking for.